# What to pass to aggfunc in pandas pivot table for summing up counters

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a data table with two columns "A" and "B", and the elements in column "B" are counters. For example,

```
c = Counter(a=4, b=2)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["group1", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2"],
                   "B": [c, c, c, c, c]})
```

I would like to create a pivot table, where I group over element values in column "A" and aggregate over column "B" by adding up the counters. I wonder what should I pass to aggfunc?

This is what I have tried, but sadly it does not work:

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['A'], values = ['B'], aggfunc = ['+'])
```

Any suggestions?

My expected output is

```
table              
  group1  Counter(a=12, b=6)   # i.e., c+c+c
  group2  Counter(a=8, b=4)    # i.e., c+c
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thanks for asking! I have added in the problem description.

Comment: `pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['A'], values = ['B'], aggfunc = ['sum'])` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely It works!! Thanks a lot! Any explanation? Sorry I'm a python beginner...

Comment: @Stupid_Guy `'+'` isn't valid function name, `'sum'` is what you probably meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `sum`.

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
A
group1    {'a': 12, 'b': 6}
group2     {'a': 8, 'b': 4}
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

Two notes:

1. Putting dictionaries into dataframe columns is usually not a good practice. I would use two columns to hold the value for `'a'` and `'b'` respectively.
2. `"B": [c, c, c, c, c]` initializes each element of column `'B'` with the same counter object.

Demo:

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'B']['a'] = 100
>>> df
Out[9]: 
        A                   B
0  group1  {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
1  group1  {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
2  group1  {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
3  group2  {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
4  group2  {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
```

You might want `"B": [c.copy() for _ in range(5)]` - if you want to keep your original design at all, that is.